# How to allow a participant to update their registration info (WP with Caldera Forms)

Tags: wordpress, civievent, caldera-forms

I know this is able to be done with Drupal/Webform but what about native in WordPress or WordPress with Caldera Forms? I would like to be able to send a tokenized link to participants which sends them to a simple form that, when submitted, changes their registration status.

WordPress 5.2.4,
CiviCRM 5.13.4